# Squid log rotation and sarg report creation errors

Tags: squid

1) My Squid usually was creating 2 files: access.log and cache.log . 
Some days ago it started creating many files like:

```
access.log.1 
access.log.2  ... until access.log.9 
cache.log.1 ... until cache.log.9
```

I could not find solution to this. Could anyone help me? 
I want it to create only 2 files: `access.log` and `cache.log`

2) My Sarg was generating Squid's report once a day according to crontab.

Some days ago it started to generate reports twice like:

```
2017Jun25-2017Jun25 
2017Jun25-2017Jun25.1
```

Why?

My crontab's content:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/sbin/squid -k rotate 
10 1 * * * /etc/webmin/sarg/generate.pl
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the settings of your system's log rotation script. It rotates system logs and deletes the oldest ones so that the hard disk isn't filled with log files.

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: Google for logrotate and you will see several articles on the software. You will find the information there.